# Running nightwatch.js tests on linux box?

Tags: linux, node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run the nightwatch automated ui tests on a linux box with Centos OS installed. I'm having trouble getting started.

Here's my test_settings configuration in nightwatch.json

```
"test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true,
                "on_failure": true,
                "on_error": true,
                "path": "./screenshots"
            },
            "detailed_option": true,
            "end_session_on_fail": false,
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "chromeOptions": {
                    "args": [
                        "use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
                        "use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

I installed the linux 64bit chrome driver. Then I installed the selenium standalong server. But when I want the nightwatch tests using node nightwatch I get an error

"Connection is refused! Selenium not started.."

How can I set up a linux box to run the nightwatch automated UI tests?

When I set start_process to false and run the selenium server separately, I get the following error:

```
14:23:41.158 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nightwatch.json looks like it's missing many objects, specifically the selenium server settings, which would explain `"Connection is refused! Selenium not started.."`. For example here's mine, and much of this will be specific to your environment:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["./tests"],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "custom_commands_path": [
    "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/lib/commands",
    "./lib/custom_commands"
  ],
  "custom_assertions_path": [
    "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/lib/assertions"
  ],

  "page_objects_path": [
    "./lib/pages"
  ],

  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
    "log_path": "reports",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver": ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "http://127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "sync_test_names": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      },
      "globals": {
        "waitForConditionTimeout": 60000
      }
    },

    "phantomjs": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "phantomjs.binary.path": "./node_modules/testarmada-magellan-nightwatch/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"
      }
    },

    "safari": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "safari"
      }
    },

    "firefox": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox"
      }
    },

    "chrome": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    },

    "sauce": {
      "selenium_host": "ondemand.saucelabs.com",
      "selenium_port": 80,
      "username": "myUserName",
      "access_key": "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "${SAUCE_BROWSER_NAME}",
        "platform": "${SAUCE_BROWSER_PLATFORM}",
        "version": "${SAUCE_BROWSER_VERSION}",
        "tunnel-identifier": "${SAUCE_TUNNEL_ID}"
      },
      "selenium": {
        "start_process": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```